# MS SQL encoding and classic .asp

Tags: sql-server, encoding, asp-classic, vbscript

Im having problems with encoding on my website. Im translating it to Polish and uses the:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
```

On top of the documents. That works fine. The problem is, when i try to show selected fields from my MS SQL database on the webspage, then something goes wrong. When i select it in the enterprise manager it shows fine. I've used the Collate: Polish_BIN in the table from where i get the data.

Here it goes wrong:

```
ConnectString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=.;UID=db.pl;PWD=Pass;Database=poland.pl"
Set forbindelse = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Forbindelse.Open ConnectString 

Do while not Rso.EOF
%>
<%=Rso("polishtext")%>
<%
Rso.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: How do you set the connection encoding when you open the database connection?

Comment: I just do this:
ConnectString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=.;UID=db.pl;PWD=Pass;Database=poland.pl"
Set forbindelse = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Forbindelse.Open ConnectString

Comment: the problem is that you are using Polish_BIN Collate when the server expects UTF-8 data. the first problem is that MS-SQL can't give you the data in UTF-8, then the only thing to do IMHO is to change the CodePage to something more related to the Polish character set. That's the only solution that i have in mind

Comment: This is worth reading http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx . I find that ordinary Notepad is fine for saving in UTF-8 format.  If you use UTF-8 encoded asp pages to insert your Polish text it should display correctly in your webpages, though you will probably see one or two strange characters in Enterprise Manager.  Russian in Enterprise manager can look like this "Ðž ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ð¸"